# There is an extra information in extracting data

Tags: python-3.x

I'am trying fetch the data from PDF using python in Juypter notebook. The data  is extracted but with some other characters  like NaN.

Comment: Please mention your problem specifically and mention necessary code what you have tried.

Comment: url="example.pdf"         try: df= read_pdf(url, pages=1)          print(df)       except Exception as e:     print("error{}".format(e))